# Prove that $X=R^{n+1}\backslash \overline{B}(0,1)$ deformation retracts to the sphere $A=C(0,2)$

Tags: general-topology

I was proving this statement and I have found a problem. I have taken the retraction $r\colon X\to A$ defined as $r(x)=\frac{2x}{\|x\|}$ and the homotopy:\begin{equation}
H\colon X\times[0,1]\to X,\quad H(x,s)=(1-s)x+sr(x).
\end{equation}
The thing is that I can't prove that $\|H(x,s)\|>1$, in order to know that the homotopy is well defined. Any ideas?

Comment: If $A = C(0,2)$ denotes the sphere with center $0$ and radius $2$, then your function $r$ does not retract to $A$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put a "2" in the definition of r. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have
$$H(x,s) = (1-s)x + s \frac{2x}{\lVert x \rVert} = \frac{(1- s)\lVert x \rVert + 2s}{\lVert x \rVert} x ,$$
thus
$$\lVert H(x,s \rVert  = \left\lvert \frac{(1- s)\lVert x \rVert + 2s}{\lVert x \rVert}\right\rvert \lVert x \rVert = \lvert (1- s)\lVert x \rVert + 2s \rvert .$$
Since $\lVert x \rVert > 1$, we get for $s < 1$
$$(1- s)\lVert x \rVert + 2s > 1-s + 2s = 1 + s \ge 1$$
and for $s=1$
$$(1- s)\lVert x \rVert + 2s =  2 > 1 .$$
Hence for all $(x,s) \in X \times [0,1]$
$$ \lvert (1- s)\lVert x \rVert + 2s \rvert > 1 $$
which completes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Let $V$ be a normed space and $v\in V$ be any vector. Then for any $t\in[0,1]$ and any $r>0$ we have

$$\lVert tv+(1-t)rv\rVert=$$
$$=\lVert \big(t+(1-t)r\big)v\rVert=$$
$$=|t+(1-t)r|\cdot\lVert v\rVert$$

Now $t+(1-t)r$ is a straight line from $r$ to $1$ in $\mathbb{R}$. And since $r>0$ then this means that $|t+(1-t)r|\geq\min(1,r)$. And this implies that

$$|t+(1-t)r|\cdot\lVert v\rVert\geq\min(1,r)\cdot\lVert v\rVert=$$
$$=\min(\lVert v\rVert,r\lVert v\rVert)$$

All in all we have

$$\lVert tv+(1-t)rv\rVert\geq\min(\lVert v\rVert, r\lVert v\rVert)$$

regardless of $t\in [0,1]$. This of course works the same if "$t$" and "$1-t$" switch places.

---

Now note that in your case we can write

$$H(v,t)=(1-t)v+t\frac{2}{\lVert v\rVert}v$$

All assumptions are satisfied, and thus

$$\lVert H(v,t)\rVert\geq\min(\lVert v\rVert, \frac{2}{\lVert v\rVert}\lVert v\rVert)=\min(\lVert v\rVert, 2)> 1$$

because $\lVert v\rVert >1$.